# Need some formatting help in the logging function in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, format

I am developing my skills in Python and now try to add some logging to my files. I run into formatting issue and cannot find any information or I ask the wrong question. 
So to it:
Some snippets of my code.

```
 import logging   
logging.basicConfig(filename='/var/log/larmlog/getandsendlogger.log',level=logging.DEBUG,format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S ')
```

I am fetching two variables from MySQL

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT omr,county FROM rico where pocnr = '%s'""" %  (pocin))
        records = cursor.fetchall()
        nystad = [record[0] for record in records]
        county = [record[1] for record in records]
logging.debug("chkomr returns nystad {} and county {}.".format(nystad,county))
```

and when I use the variables in the log it looks like this

> 2017-12-05 02:46:02  - root - DEBUG - chkomr returns nystad [None] and county [u'J\xf6nk\xf6pings l\xe4n'].

Why and how can I correct it? Should be strings with Swedish. The log should say Jönköpings län. My code should be set to utf-8.

I have not asked so many questions here and probably messed up the question with codeblocks and so. Just ask if you need more code or explanation.

Comment: I think loggers use the old percent sign syntax. `log.info('%s %s', foo, bar)`

Comment: I don't understand, is there any error in the code or python throws incorrect formatting issue. In latter case you may try "yapf" from here https://github.com/google/yapf

Comment: If i use %s i get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem but i am not sure why i have to extract the data twice. Just happy my loggs start to look good. :D

```
logging.debug('chkomr returns nystad %s and county %s.' % (nystad[0],county[0]))
```